# cannot play sound on android on tap of a button

Tags: nativescript

I just tried to play sound on tap of a button using

```
let decorView = app.android.startActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
```

and it is giving

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWindow' of undefined

`the demo is here`

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=5lqiJZ

- I need to play sound while tapping a button
- Also i need to play custom sounds

**update**

- i got to know `console.log(app.android.startActivity);` is undefined.
- So earlier StartActivity is working. But now it was not working.
- i ran this offline on vscode and there it is not giving error but sound was not playing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `foregroundActivity` instead of the `startActivity`.

```
let decorView = app.android.foregroundActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
```

Modified Playground demo [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=5lqiJZ&v=3).